# importance of JTable model?

Tags: java, swing

What is the importance of JTable model.Does all the swing components has model associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Swing uses the Model-View-controller design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)). As such, most components provided with Swing have indeed an associated model (not all of them, though).

This allows you to separate the rendering part from the data part. I would recommend you to use your own model for JTable, especially if you are manipulating and/or changing data from it.

However, if you don't have such need, and your JTable is only something you use once, in a small corner of your program, with fixed datas, you can also manipulate data directly from the JTable, neglecting the MVC pattern. A JTable created without specifying a model will create [its own model](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), and the [JTable class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) provides methods to manipulate the data directly, for such cases.

Comment: I agree with you, but, in my opinion, the case where you should directly use JTable is only for GUI prototyping.

Comment: @Sylvain - yes, this, or very small programs in which the table is only fed with "manual" datas. Any other case should be using the TableModel.

Answer (score 2):

please have a look at MVC design pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

and yes, most of the java swing components have models, see:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html